# Why am I getting a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to compile a simple hello world function in c++. After I compile it, I run it and get "Segmentation fault". Can someone shed some light on this?

I am compiling this from a Linux command line using the following command:

> g++ hello.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably my error. Not close enough to c#?

Comment: Your code works fine. I don't see any reason for a segfault.

Comment: Is this the exact code you compiled?  Should work.

Comment: I just checked with my host and they are telling me that I have to install gcc. I run gcc from the command line and get "no input files" so it is already installed.

Comment: Who/what is "they"?  Maybe your gcc installation is broken and you should try reinstalling.

Answer (score 6):

The program itself looks OK. I would guess there's some quirk in your compilation environment that is causing the segfault.

Your best bet is to run this in the debugger (gdb) -- that will tell you where it's crashing, which will help you figure out what the problem is.

To do this, compile like this:

```
g++ -g -o hello hello.cpp
```

then run gdb:

```
gdb hello
```

and at the gdb prompt type

```
run
```

to run the program. When it crashes, type

```
bt
```

which will give you a stacktrace that will -- hopefully -- help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: Martin, I ran the first line and I never get the opportunity to enter anything else; the app just complies the out file.

Comment: @Jim: What's "the app"?  What's "the out file"?

Comment: Sorry Alok. The app is the little hello world "application" and the out file is the file that was compiled and named a.out.

Comment: Am I running this correctly? I am running it like this: ./a.out

Comment: @Jim: Do you mean you ran `g++ -g -o hello hello.cpp` and it generated an `a.out` file and not a file named `hello`? (Even so, you can substitute `gdb a.out` for step 2.)

Comment: @Jim: The "-o hello" option I added to the g++ command causes the compiler to write the executable to a file called "hello" (instead of the default, a.out, which is not usually what you want). Once this is compiled, use "gdb hello" to start the debugger, then enter the "run" command to run the program.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with that code, so you will have to investigate first your compiler, then your hardware.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the consensus but I have no idea how to troubleshoot at the server level.

Answer (score 1):

Compile it like this

g++ -Bstatic -static hello.cpp

and then run ./a.out

If this doesn't seg fault, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is your culprit.

Comment: +1 for the `-static` approach. However I do not believe that is has to do with LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I think that there is something wrong with the g++ installation.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a longshot, but try to change `int main()` to `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: Hi Viktor, I tried that and it compiled uneventfully. I ran it and got the same exact result. segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

It's late but might useful:

A simple cxx program compiled runs with core dump / segment fault, the reasons could be:

- broken gcc installation, broken .so links (libstdc++.so ...)

This commonly happens in the gcc installation is compiled from source.

The workaround is preloading the right lib64/ folder via LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=YOUR_GCC_INSTALLATION/lib64 ./hello
# Or
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=YOUR_GCC_INSTALLATION/lib64/libstdc++.so ./hello
```

If so, put the definition as system wide:

```bash
sudo echo "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=YOUR_GCC_INSTALLATION/lib64" >/etc/profile.d/your_gcc
```

and reboot.